# Add a new column to count distinct of multiple columns (row wise) in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, NA is the missing value, not string

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(142, 1, 4),
             B = c("NA",1,5),
             c = c("NA","NA","NA"),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to add a new column `D` to show count distinct value of both `A`, `B` and `C` but we don't count `NA` in. The Desire output is the following:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(142, 1, 4),
             B = c("NA",1,5),
             c = c("NA","NA","NA"),
             D = c(1, 1, 2),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `NA`'s are real `NA`'s and not string `"NA"`s using `dplyr` (>= 1.0.0) you can do :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(D = n_distinct(na.omit(c_across())))

#     A     B c         D
#  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> <int>
#1   142    NA NA        1
#2     1     1 NA        1
#3     4     5 NA        2
```

**data**

```
df <- type.convert(df)
```

Comment: hi it seems my R doesn't have the function c_across and I installed dev tools and i still couldn't find c_accross

Comment: you need `dplyr`>= 1.0.0. Try `install.packages('dplyr')` to get the latest dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

We can just use `base R`

```
df$D <- apply(df, 1, function(x) length(unique(na.omit(x))))
df$D
#[1] 1 2 2
```